# How do I call model function on create event? Laravel-5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, referrals

I'm trying to create a referral url when a user is first created.
My function inside my User model looks like this:

```
private function make_url()
{
    $url = str_random(40);
    $this->referral_url->url = $url;
    if ($this->save()){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Within the model, I've tried doing this but didn't work

```
USER::creating(function ($this){
$this->make_url();
})
```

I also tried calling it in my User Controller within the create user action

```
public function create(UserRequest $request)
{
$data = $request->all()
$data['password']= bcrypt($request->input('password'));

if($user=User::create($data))
{
  $user->make_url();
}
}
```

I get this error in return

```
Indirect modification of overloaded property App\User::$referral_url has no effect
```

Thanks in advance for your help guys =]

p.s: If there's a better way to go about creating referral urls please tell me.

**update**

My entire user model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword as CanResetPasswordContract;

class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract, CanResetPasswordContract
{
    use Authenticatable, CanResetPassword;

    protected $table = 'users';

    protected $fillable = [
                            'first_name',
                            'last_name',
                            'url',
                            'email',
                            'password',
                            'answer_1',
                            'answer_2',
                            'answer_3'
                            ];                           


    protected $hidden = ['password', 'remember_token'];


    public function make_url()
    {
        $url = str_random(40);
        $this->referral_url->url = $url;
        if ($this->save()){
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function user_info()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\UserInfo');
    }

    public function sec_questions()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\SecurityQuestions');
    }

    public function referral_url()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\ReferralUrl');
    }
}
```

**update**
I modified the function in the model to look like this now.

```
public function make_url()
{
    $url = str_random(40);
    $referral_url = $this->referral_url;
    $referral_url = new ReferralUrl();
    $referral_url->user_id = $this->id;
    $referral_url->url = $url;
    if ($referral_url->save()){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

When I call

```
$user->make_url()
```

I'm able to create it and it shows up in my db, but I also get the error-

```
Trying to get property of non-object
```

Comment: What does the rest of your user model look like?

Comment: i updated the post with entire user model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally the `creating` method should be called within `boot()`:

```
public static function boot() {
    parent::boot();

    static::creating(function ($model) {
        $model->foo = 'bar';
    });
}
```

This would then be called automatically *before* the model is saved for the first time.

The problem that I see with your code is that you're attempting to modify a relation which *doesn't exist yet*.

So to explain, the `hasOne` method will attempt to join the current model to the remote model (in your case a `ReferralUrl` model) in SQL, but it can't do that before you save your model because your model *doesn't exist* in the database.

With your second attempt, the `ReferralUrl` object is the one that is changing, so that is the one that you need to save:

```
public function make_url() {
    $url = str_random(40);
    $referral_url = $this->referral_url
    $referral_url->url = $url;
    if ($referral_url->save()){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I updated my post.  When I call on the function in my controller it saves into my db, but I'm also getting an error.

Comment: take `$referral_url = $this->referral_url;` (line 2) out of your updated function.

Comment: ahh i see,  Since I'm instantiating a new referral obj i didn't need that.